# Xunit Complete List of Command Line Options

Tags: command-line, xunit, xunit.net

Does anybody have a complete list of command line options for running Xunit tests from the console?

I have around 100 tests, lets say broken up into 10 separate classes, each class has 10 tests

Class1
Test1
Test2
...

Class2
Test1
Test2
...

etc

I can trigger running all of these tests by navigating to my test directory and using 'dotnet test'.
I have found documentation that says -? diplays all the command line options (but this isn't the full list apparently) https://livebook.manning.com/book/dotnet-core-in-action/appendix-b/4

The official documentation https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel
says i can use for example '-parallel all' but when it run

dotnet test -parallel all

I get

\repos\test-automation-framework\framework>dotnet test -parallel all
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: -parallel

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"

I would like to get to a stage where I can run all my tests in parallel but limit the thread count to lets say 6, so I will run my entire suite of tests, 6 tests at a time.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass some command line arguments to Xunit. But when you run `dotnet test` it actually applies arguments to `dotnet` command instead.

You can turn on parallelization and other features by using [configuration files](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files) instead.

*xunit.config.json*

```json
{
    "parallelizeAssembly": true
}
```

Arguments you did mention (e.g. `--parallel`) do exist but not in `dotnet` context. You can run Xunit manually by using **console runner**. It is present in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.console/)  and on [GitHub](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/main/src/xunit.v3.runner.console/ConsoleRunner.cs) as a part of xunit repo.

Here's it's output:

```sh
$ .\xunit.console.exe
xUnit.net Console Runner v2.4.1 (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.6.1, runtime: 4.0.30319.42000)
Copyright (C) .NET Foundation.

usage: xunit.console <assemblyFile> [configFile] [assemblyFile [configFile]...] [options] [reporter] [resultFormat filename [...]]

Note: Configuration files must end in .json (for JSON) or .config (for XML)

Valid options:
  -nologo                : do not show the copyright message
  -nocolor               : do not output results with colors
  -failskips             : convert skipped tests into failures
  -stoponfail            : stop on first test failure
  -parallel option       : set parallelization based on option
                         :   none        - turn off all parallelization
                         :   collections - only parallelize collections
                         :   assemblies  - only parallelize assemblies
                         :   all         - parallelize assemblies & collections
  -maxthreads count      : maximum thread count for collection parallelization
                         :   default   - run with default (1 thread per CPU thread)
                         :   unlimited - run with unbounded thread count
                         :   (number)  - limit task thread pool size to 'count'
  -appdomains mode       : choose an app domain mode
                         :   ifavailable - choose based on library type
                         :   required    - force app domains on
                         :   denied      - force app domains off
  -noshadow              : do not shadow copy assemblies
  -wait                  : wait for input after completion
  -diagnostics           : enable diagnostics messages for all test assemblies
  -internaldiagnostics   : enable internal diagnostics messages for all test assemblies
  -debug                 : launch the debugger to debug the tests
  -serialize             : serialize all test cases (for diagnostic purposes only)
  -trait "name=value"    : only run tests with matching name/value traits
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an OR operation
  -notrait "name=value"  : do not run tests with matching name/value traits
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an AND operation
  -method "name"         : run a given test method (can be fully specified or use a wildcard;
                         : i.e., 'MyNamespace.MyClass.MyTestMethod' or '*.MyTestMethod')
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an OR operation
  -nomethod "name"       : do not run a given test method (can be fully specified or use a wildcard;
                         : i.e., 'MyNamespace.MyClass.MyTestMethod' or '*.MyTestMethod')
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an AND operation
  -class "name"          : run all methods in a given test class (should be fully
                         : specified; i.e., 'MyNamespace.MyClass')
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an OR operation
  -noclass "name"        : do not run any methods in a given test class (should be fully
                         : specified; i.e., 'MyNamespace.MyClass')
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an AND operation
  -namespace "name"      : run all methods in a given namespace (i.e.,
                         : 'MyNamespace.MySubNamespace')
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an OR operation
  -nonamespace "name"    : do not run any methods in a given namespace (i.e.,
                         : 'MyNamespace.MySubNamespace')
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an AND operation
  -noautoreporters       : do not allow reporters to be auto-enabled by environment
                         : (for example, auto-detecting TeamCity or AppVeyor)

Reporters: (optional, choose only one)
  -appveyor              : forces AppVeyor CI mode (normally auto-detected)
  -json                  : show progress messages in JSON format
  -quiet                 : do not show progress messages
  -teamcity              : forces TeamCity mode (normally auto-detected)
  -verbose               : show verbose progress messages
  -vsts                  : forces VSTS CI mode (normally auto-detected)

Result formats: (optional, choose one or more)
  -xml <filename>        : output results to xUnit.net v2 XML file
  -xmlv1 <filename>      : output results to xUnit.net v1 XML file
  -html <filename>       : output results to HTML file
  -nunit <filename>      : output results to NUnit v2.5 XML file
  -junit <filename>      : output results to JUnit XML file
```